# At each iteration update dictionary with other dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

Inside a for loop I create the model_type_x for a toy_code (e.g. Manufacturer_Model_name) and an estimator assigned to that toy_code. So for example,

*toy example*

```
dataset=pd.DataFrame({'toy_code':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                      'Manufacturer': ['CoolerInc', 'CoolerInc', 'CoolerInc', 'ABCInc', 'ABCInc'],
                      'Model_Estimator': [model_estimator_1, model_estimator_2, model_estimator_3, model_estimator_4, model_estimator_5]
```

*For the sake of the problem let's pretend that "model estimator" is a column in the DataFrame. In my real example this is a machine learning model calculated inside the loop.*

```
dictionary_1={}
toy_code=dataset['toy_code'].unique().tolist() #list of code ids [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for code in toy_code:
    model_type_x=dataset['Manufacturer'][dataset['toy_code']==code].iloc[0]
    model_estimator= dataset['Model_Estimator'][dataset['toy_code']==code].iloc[0]

    dictionary_1[code]=model_estimator
```

**output so far**

```
dictionary_1={"1": model_estimator_type_code_1,
              "2": model_estimator_type_code_2,
              "3": model_estimator_type_code_3,
              "4": model_estimator_type_code_4,
              "5": model_estimator_type_code_5}
```

So far so good, although my final output I don't want to be structured in the way above. I need a different approach.

My desired output is to "group" each model_estimator by the manufacturer. The estimator will be part of a dictionary with key:type-code and value:model_estimator

**My desired output**:

```
dictionary_1_grouped={"CoolerInc": {"1": model_estimator_type_code_1,
                            "2": model_estimator_type_code_2,
                            "3": model_estimator_type_code_3},
              "ABCInc": {"4": model_estimator_type_code_4,
                         "5": model_estimator_type_code_5}
             }
```

**My code so far**

```
for code in toy_code:
    model_type_x=dataset['Manufacturer'][dataset['toy_code']==code].iloc[0]
    model_estimator= dataset['Model_Estimator'][dataset['toy_code']==code].iloc[0]

    dictionary_1.update({asset_model:{i:best_classifier_asset_id}})
```

With this code I get my desired output in a very close way.

```
{'CoolerInc': {'3': model_estimator_3},
 'ABCInc': {'5': model_estimator_5}}
```

As you can see in the above dictionary I can save the model_estimators by manufacturer. Although the toy_codes 1, 2 which have the same manufacturer with toy_code 3 are not saved but rather overwritten. How can I avoid this?

I hope that my question is crystal clear. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you sure that your first ouput `dictionary_1` is a valid python dict ?

Comment: yeah its actually, key = Manufacturer, value=pipeline object of scikit-learn

Comment: Your actuel output can't be as you have duplicate keys

Comment: @ChihebNexus ```dictionary_1={CoolerInc': Pipeline(steps=[('gradientboost_classifier',
                  GradientBoostingClassifier(learning_rate=0.001, max_depth=2,
                                             random_state=123))]),....}```

Comment: dicts in python have a unique keys :/

Comment: So they can't be grouped?..Under the same Manufacturer....Let me edit then

Comment: @ChihebNexus Please check my update :)

Comment: Now, what's the logic behind groupping your dict values ?

Comment: sorry but your question and example still not clear.

Comment: My question is actually how can I get from dictionary_1 to dictionary_1_grouped. I guess I have to make something inside the loop. And maybe introduce a second dictionary that I will append other dictionaries

Comment: @ChihebNexus can you please check my code snippet update? :)

Comment: @azro can you please check my code snippet update? :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this question my following this approach:

```
dict_a = [{asset_model: [{i:model_estimator}]}]
result_dict = {}

    for d in dict_a:
        for k, v in d.items():
            dictionary_1.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
```

The output:

```
{'CoolerInc': [{'1': model_estimator_1},
               {'2': model_estimator_2},
               {'3': model_estimator_3}],
 'ABCInc': [{'4': model_estimator_4},
            {'5': model_estimator_5}]}
```

A list of dictionaries. It's actually the output I want in a list but it is still very close to the desired output. So I will keep it as it is.